# Can you help me identify the name of the artist on my painting? (Characters identified: 雲茜)

Tags: character-identification, seal

I inherited a painting which I think is on silk. I would like to know more about it. I think it was probably bought in the mid-twentieth century by my great aunt.

I would love to know the name of the artist in English. Thank you for any help you can give me about this painting.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I googled for a while, I think she doesn't have a famous English name. Her name in chineses is 云茜 or 雲茜 in traditional chinese. You could google this and some kind of this painting  will come out.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

According to 百度百科, she is the spouse of the painter [聂干因](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E8%81%82%E5%B9%B2%E5%9B%A0). Moreover, it seems that her real name is 云南琴 whereas 云茜 is her art name (according to several auction websites, to verify.).